# Ajax/jQuery "Like" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sql-like

I'm very new to JavaScript, and I have been experimenting with basic jQuery and ajax functions, now I am trying to create a "Like" or "Rep" button for profiles on my website, I have written up a pretty basic code, however it doesn't work, as it doesn't seem to post anything when I click the button.

Here is my JavaScript (I do have the latest jQuery embedded on my page):

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".rep").on("click", function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "add.php",
                data: ({ profile: $(".rep").attr('id') }),
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.status == 'success') {
                        $('.rep').html('N');
                    } else {
                        $('.rep').html('N');
                    }
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now my HTML elements:

```
<div class="rep" id="Username">O</div>
```

And finally my PHP script:

```
<?php
    include ("config.php");
    $to = $_POST["profile"];
    $from = $myUser;
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $date = date("M j, Y");

    if($to !== "" && $from !==""){
        $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rep WHERE to='$to' AND from='$from' AND date = '$date'");
        $n = mysql_num_rows($q);

        if($n == 0){
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rep (to, from, ip, date) VALUES ('$to', '$from', '$ip', '$date')");
            if($query){
                $data['status'] = 'success';
            } else {
                $data['status'] = 'error';
            }
        } else if($n !== 0){
            $data['status'] = 'error';
        }
    }
?>
```

Really can't get my head around it enough to make this work, so if someone could point me in the right direction whilst explaining what was wrong, that'd be great!

Comment: Wouldn't profile: $(".rep").attr('id') only return 'Username'? Try: $(".rep").html()

Comment: It's supposed to return username, that's what I want to post, I will populate that attribute with the actual profile username once the script is complete.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery live() was removed from jQuery as of version 1.9.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Try click() or on('click')

EDIT (that wasn't the problem)

The php file needs to return a json-encoded string that looks like this:

```
{name: 'bob', success: true, some_property: 'a string'}
```

and so forth for all the values you want in the return data.

I generally do this:

```
$data['success'] = true; // not needed for jquery but if you want to check it
$data['name'] = 'bob';

echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

see if that works.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the old code, I've already fixed that and the state of the element changes to "N" as I would like, but it does that for the error too atm (I put "E" to test and it showed that) + the query isn't added to the database.

Comment: It could be an error in the php file and you might be able to tell if you check the response in the browser. In Chrome you can use View > Developer > Developer Tools, then select Network to see the requests and responses. My hunch is that mysql is throwing an error because the values are not escaped properly. I usually use a database abstraction library or ORM to interact with the database because it takes care of all that stuff. You'll get it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

use this format

```
$(document).on("click", ".rep", function () {

var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var s = {
        "profile": d
    };


    $.ajax({

        url: "add.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: s,
        success: function (data) {
          // but what you want  

        },

    });


    return false;
});
```

Comment: <div class="rep" id="Username">like</div> <<<< >>>> but in the id tag the profile and its will be working

Comment: I already fixed that where you put id rather than ID and it didn't work still, I think it is my PHP.

Comment: make sure for this var $to = $_POST["profile"];
$from = $myUser;

Comment: Write to me, the HTML code of "rep" that you have without any modification

Comment: <div class="rep" id="Username">O</div>

Comment: <div class="rep" id="put here the value of profile in php code ">O</div>  and give the result

Answer (score 0):

first off all, chage .html('n') to .text('n');

add to your ajax function

```
error: function (error) {
                  console.log(error); //or alert(error);
              }
```

and you will receive response

Comment: I added this and received nothing in the JavaScript console, it's down to the PHP surely.

Comment: So, you have no errors ) Maybe use json_encode for $data['bla']

Comment: how many <div class="rep" id="Username">O</div> you have on form?

Comment: Just that one, no others - Do you know what the error could be then?

Comment: can you try  if(data.status == 'success') {
       $('.rep').text('s');
       } else {
       $('.rep').text('e');
       }
       }   , your div will give text 's' or 'e' ?

Comment: I did that and it was throwing the error one :/ I'm going to try troubleshoot/debug the php now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo out the result in the php file so the javascript receives the right result in the data parameter